# error with ob_start() using user defined function inside

Tags: php, web, buffer

```
function d() {
            return "from d output\n";

        }
        ob_start();
        //var_dump("any thing\n");
        d();
        $a= ob_get_clean();
        echo "$a";
```

i'm starting doing things in php. I've used this code but in this case no output is being printed to the browser. But whenever I'm using code like`var_dump("anything\n");` within the two `ob_` block I'm getting output. My question is what is the difference between the output of `var_dump()` and my handwritten function `d()` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
d();
```

... into this:

```
echo d();
```

Invoking a function does not automatically print its return value. Or, if you want to mimic `var_dump()`'s behaviour:

```
function d() {
    echo "from d output\n";
}
```

Comment: @me.deeiip - Because you script does not print anything?

Comment: you mean to say to create content for buffer I've to print something, not to return something.